# I need to open embedded google doc links in the parent window?

Tags: iframe, documentation, hyperlink, parent

OK,

I would like to use I would like to use embedded google documents as the text component to my pages content. I already have the iframes set and everything looks fine. The problem is that i cannot get the iframe links to open in the parent window.

I know that if I could add target="parent" to the hrefs within the iframe I could make it work, but I cannot edit the html within the google doc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pretty old question, but have you got any solution?

Comment: If you use blogger, instead of google docs, then you can edit the html of your posts directly. This will give you a similar environment to Google docs and more control of the content.

Comment: But i would also mention that in the end, for this project, I just gave in and leaned php and mysql and did a more traditional content management system. The blogger solution was a good stopgap while i learned, but these kinds of solutions are never as good as just putting in the time and effort to "do it right."

Comment: Thank you a lot for the response. The point is that I have a link to the PDF and I'd like to render a page with Google Docs Viewer iframe to show PDF content embedded into my *mobile* web application. As I see there is no way to tell Google Viewer open "download" link in the parent window because of same-origin policy. Anyway thanks.